# A question onMarkov chain

Tags: markov-chains

> The diffusion of electrons and holes across a potential barrier in an electronic devise is modelled as follows. There are $m$ black balls (electrons) in urn $A$ and $m$ white balls (holes) in urn $B$. We perform independent trials, in each of which a ball is selected at random from each urn and the selected ball from urn $A$ is placed in urn $B$, while that from urn $B$ is placed in $A.$ Consider the Markov chain representing the number of black balls in urn $A$ immediately after the $n − th$ trial. Then how to find the Transition Probability Matrix of the Markov Chain?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there a specific part of the problem that results problematic for you?

Comment: You might start by deciding what the state space looks like.